# Stop Ubuntu laptop from suspending when external diplay goes off when lid is closed

Tags: linux, laptop, sleep, power-management, external-display

I work with a single external display and I'd like to know if it's possible to keep my laptop lid closed at all times.

If the external display is used I can close the lid, and the laptop will not go to sleep. This is great. However, if I'm inactive for a while, the display will enter some kind of standby mode to save power, and this causes the laptop to go to sleep.

If it's possible I'd like to:

- allow the display to keep entering this standby mode, and just keep the laptop working anyway,
- retain the ability to suspend on demand with `sudo systemcl suspend`.

I've tried searching for problems like this but it seems everyone has *some* problem with suspension and hibernation so it's tough to find anything.

Comment: You can set it to never turn off the monitor in system settings > energy.